# ob_clean doesn't remove header

Tags: php

I used header redirect between ob_start and ob_clean, but it still redirected.

I just want to know why ob_clean() doesn't work.Thank you!

```
ob_start();
header("location:../index.html");
ob_clean()
ob_end()
```

**Note: This was reported and confirmed being a bug in PHP at the point in time the question was asked. It has been resolved in newer versions.**

Comment: The output buffer is for the response body only, not the header.

Answer (score 1):

This is because output buffering doesn't affect headers.

The manual for [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) says:

> While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script **(other than headers)**

(my bold).

Therefore `ob_clean()` doesn't remove the header which you created.

Comment: Sure it affects headers ;) Haven't you tried this? https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/7953

Comment: @Tim it sounds like it's probably ob_gzhandler which affects the header in your scenario, not the core output buffering functionality. Have you checked what headers the browser actually receives in that particular case? I haven't used it but per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php it sounds like it might alter the content-encoding header specifically

Comment: Yes I checked the headers. It seems the bug was confirmed being a problem with ob_gzhandler. This went a bit off topic so I will end it there. Thanks for the reply. :)